# Process HTML Entities in CDATA Element

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am currently working on a XSLT transformation to change the structure of some XML documents into a structure, which is needed by an external service provider.

My source document contains an a very large element with CDATA content like this:

```
<ABC>
        <![CDATA[
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br><br>
        onsetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor<br>
        At vero eos et &auml;ccusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum
        ..."LARGE CONTENT"...
        ]]>
</ABC>
```

Please note, that the text contains unclosed <br> Elements and many different HTML entities like &auml;

The desired result in my destination document should look like this:

```
<p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br/><br/>
        onsetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor<br/>
        At vero eos et äccusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum
        ...&quot;LARGE CONTENT&quot;...
</p>
```

No CDATA, the <br> elements were closed, so I have well formed XML and the HTML entities were transformed to UTF characters, like in the example: &auml; --> ä 
Except the entities, which you have to escape for XML, like <,>,",',&

My way to process this:

```
<xsl:template match="ABC">

    <xsl:variable name="temp" select="replace(text(),'&amp;auml;','ä')"/>

    <!--[... many replacement rules for HTML entities...]-->

    <xsl:value-of select="replace($temp,'&lt;br&gt;','&lt;br/&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

</xsl:template>
```

This template fulfills its requirements, but there are many replacement rules and it seems to be very circumstantial and ineffective.

Is there a better way to process this unescaping of HTML entities?

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? `replace` suggests it is an XSLT 2.0 processor and the commercial versions of Saxon 9 (PE, EE) have an extension function `parse-html` http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/parse-html that should do the job (well, it parses a HTML document so you might need to use `saxon:parse-html(concat('&lt;html>', ., '&lt/html>'))`).

Comment: Hi Martin. I use Oxygen XML IDE. So I guess I can use Saxon 9 (PE,EE). I'll give it a try! Thank you!

Comment: saxon:parse-html() helped a lot! Should I add that as answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse a fragment of HTML or a HTML document and you use a commercial version of Saxon 9 (PE or EE) then it provides HTML parsing support with the help of TagSoup exposed as an extension function `saxon:parse-html` (in the namespace `http://saxon.sf.net/`, see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/parse-html) which could be called in

```
<xsl:template match="ABC">
  <p>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="saxon:parse-html(.)/node()"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

or similar to process the nodes created by the `TagSoup` `HTML` parser.